# Constrain scrolling list to container div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to constrain my tab list to the container div (#tabs).

http://jsbin.com/uzopun/1/

Any ideas to get me started.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your `#tab` div need to be 400px? If you set it's width to `auto` the tab list will be properly constrained.

Comment: Isn't that already the case in your demo?

Comment: Well let me clarify - I'd like to continue to scroll the list, but I'd like the first li to stop at at the left:0 position when it reaches it and the same for the right side. Does the width need to be fixed? No - in fact I'd like to hide the buttons on resize when I don't need them. Hope that helps a bit.